# How to delete component of BOM (bill of material) in SAP

Tags: sap-erp

I want to delete the component (raw material) of a BOM without making any changes in ABAP coding.

Please tell me know if we have any transaction for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use transaction 'CS02'.

CS02 – Change Material BOM
SAP transaction CS02 (Change Material BOM) is classified in the Logistics – General module under application component Bills of Material and runs R/3 Application development: PP Bills of Material program SAPMC29S upon execution

Check this [link](http://www.saptransactions.com/codes/CS02/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CS02 (Change BOM) T-code to delete the Component of the BOM (Bill Of Material), if you required to delete the multiple BOM Component use LSMW Script.